# Javascript image preload doesn't correctly work

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, node.js, preload

I have a JS/jQuery scripts which appends images dynamically on page. I am using node as server.
I've added logs server side and I noticed that everytime there is an "append" done, the page asks the server for the image, even if it is always the same two images which are appended.
Now, this happens on Chrome, but not on Mozilla, where the images are loaded only once.
I thought this would be the cache; but cache isn't disabled.
Also, I've tried doing some preloading by creating an Image object with the right src in the beginning of the page : same problem.
Even if it is a browser cache setting, I don't want to build a website where users with cache disabled spam my server with useless requests of the same images...
Any advice ?

Comment: Which cache-headers do you send?

Answer (score -1):

You should also try/research preloading images with other techniques too if it fits to your requirements and if JS preloading is too complicated. Good discussion is found here

http://perishablepress.com/pure-css-better-image-preloading-without-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for the advice but how should CSS preloading resolve this problem ? In addition, I'd like to make something dynamic (maybe I'll have to preload a large number of images), with CSS I'd have to write every preload, while in JS a simple loop can resolve that.